# Game where you guess whether something is true

Tags: identify-this-game

Once at a board game café in Toronto, some friends and I played a game I really enjoyed. I can't seem to remember its name or find it by Googling relevant phrases.

The premise was: A card is drawn that has some item of trivia. Unlike most trivia games, this is intended to be unreasonably obscure, something the vast majority of players are unlikely to know. Each player puts down a chip to guess whether the statement is true or false, as well as an optional "certainty" chip that doubles their points gained or lost for the guess.

The idea is not to test the breadth and randomness of your knowledge, but to test your intuition about what sorts of things could be true of the reality we live in. You evaluate plausibility.

Can anyone who's played or seen this game identify it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like [Fact or Crap](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/3990/fact-or-crap).

[image]

Comment: That's it! I see from the ratings that not many people like it as much as I do, but what can ya do. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about what BGG users say.

Comment: Re: "I wouldn't worry too much about what BGG users say." Indeed. I mean, if you think pinecone flavored ice cream is the bee's knees and you eat it every night after dinner, who cares if everyone else thinks it's disgusting. Go right ahead and eat the ice cream and to heck with what the rest of the world thinks. That being said, there's nothing wrong with trying out new flavors, and BGG can be an excellent resource for discovering what might be your next favorite flavor of 'Obscure Trivia Party Game'.